# Tooltip is not showing on mouseover from monthview of fullcalender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, fullcalendar

In my calender.aspx page the default calender view is yearview and I am showing the tooltip message using the below code

```
$('.fc-day-number').mouseover(function () {}
```

First time the tooltip message is showing perfectly but when I'm changing yearview to monthview the tooltip message showing functionality is not working.
Even the "mouseover" function is not calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.fc-day-number',function(){});
```